# Continuous time Uniform Integrability and convergence in L1 for (super)martingale

Tags: convergence-divergence, martingales, uniform-integrability

I need to prove the following theorem by reasoning as in discrete-time, since we have proven this theorem in discrete time.

***Theorem*** Let $M$ be a right-continuous supermartingale that is bounded in $L^1$. Show the following: 
1) If $M$ is uniformly integrable, then $M_t \to M_\infty$ a.s. and in $L^1$ and $E(M_\infty | \mathcal{F}_t) \leq M_t$ a.s. with equality if $M$ is a martingale.
2) If $M$ is a martingale and $M_t \to M_\infty$ in $L^1$ as $t \to \infty$, then $M$ is uniformly integrable.

How can I proof this by reasoning as in discrete time? First I was thinking that we can use $ \mathbb{Q}$. However I think we can not use the theorem in discrete time for this, because $ \mathbb{Q}$ is not discrete time. An other possibility is maybe using dyadic rationals.

Can anyone give me some help?
Thanks

Comment: The first is called Doob's Martingale Convergence Theorem. I am sure you could find several proofs of it with a simple search on the internet.

Answer (score 2):

1) The first step to show is that we can restrict to take a limit along rational time-sequences. In other words, that $M_t \to M_\infty$ if and only if
\begin{equation} \lim_{q\to\infty} M_q = M_\infty. \quad (1) \end{equation}

This is in fact non-trivial, so assume (1) holds. Fix $\epsilon>0$ and $\omega \in \Omega$ for which $M_q(\omega)\to M_\infty(\omega)$. Then there exists a number $a=a_{\omega,\epsilon}>0$ such that $|M_q(\omega) - M_\infty(\omega)|<\epsilon$ for all $q>a$. Now let $t<a$ be arbitrary. Since $M$ is right-continuous, there exists $q'>t$ such that $|M_{q'}(\omega) - M_\infty(\omega)|<\epsilon$. By triangle inequality, it follows that $$|M_q(\omega) - M_\infty(\omega)|\leq |M_{q'}(\omega) - M_\infty(\omega)| + |M_{t}(\omega) - M_{q'}(\omega)|<2 \epsilon.$$
This proves that $M_t(\omega) \to M_\infty(\omega)$, $t\to\infty$ for all $\omega \in \Omega$.

To prove convergence to a finite $\mathcal{F}_\infty$-measurable, integrable limit, we may assume that $M$ is indexed by the countable set $Q^+$. The proof can now be finished by using the discrete case proof, and using an upcrossing inequality for continuous time martingales.

2) Hint: Use the fact that if $M_\infty$ is an integrable random variable then the class
$$ \mathcal{C} = \left\{ \mathbb{E}[M_\infty | \mathcal{A}] \mid \mathcal{A} \text{ is a sub $\sigma$-algebra of } \mathcal{F}_\infty\right\}. $$
is uniformly integrable.

Comment: Since $M$ is a supermartingale we have,
$ \mathbb{E}\left[ 1_{A} M_t \right] \leq \mathbb{E}\left[ 1_{A} M_s \right],$
for all $A \in \mathcal{F}_s$ and $t \geq s$. Now since 
$ \left| 1_A M_t - 1_A M_\infty \right| \leq 1_A \left| M_t - M_\infty \right| \leq \left| M_t - M_\infty \right|,$
then by using  as stated above we have that $1_A M_t \to 1_A M_\infty$ in $L^1$ if $t\to\infty$. Taking the limit $t \to \infty$ in the first equation gives us that
$ \mathbb{E}\left[ 1_{A} M_\infty \right] \leq \mathbb{E}\left[ 1_{A} M_s \right], \quad A \in \mathcal{F}_s$. Which proves $L^1$ convergence

Comment: Now look at the proof of the discrete case and just replace the upcrossings in discrete time to continuous time. Just mimic the proof and it should follow.

Comment: My question is: why do we have that $M_q \to M_\infty$ in $L1$? We can not use the discrete time case for this in my opinion since the rationals are not discrete.